# VBScript Regex strange output

Tags: regex, vba, excel

I am trying to split string in Excel using Regex:
Here is the string to be matched:

```
Powerunit: .75HP 
Powerunit: 1HP
```

Expected out put:

```
Powerunit: 
.75
HP
```

The code I have written so far:

```
Sub simpleRegex()
    Dim strPattern As String: strPattern = "(Powerunit: )(\.?[0-9]{1,2})(HP)"        
    Dim regEx As New RegExp
    Dim strInput As String
    Dim Myrange As Range    
    Sheet4.Activate        
    Set Myrange = ActiveSheet.Range("b1:b6")
Dim c As Range    
    If strPattern <> "" Then
            For Each c In Myrange.Cells
                                strInput = c.value                                    
                                With regEx
                                    .Global = True
                                    .MultiLine = True
                                    .IgnoreCase = False
                                    .Pattern = strPattern
                                End With                            
                                If regEx.Test(strInput) Then                                            
                                        ActiveSheet.Range("G" & c.Row).value = regEx.Replace(strInput, "$1")
                                        ActiveSheet.Range("H" & c.Row).value = regEx.Replace(strInput, "$2")
                                        ActiveSheet.Range("I" & c.Row).value = regEx.Replace(strInput, "$3")
                                    Else
                                        MsgBox ("Not matched")
                                End If
             Next
    End If
End Sub
```

I am just interested in the HP value (i.e. .75 or 1); But I can't seem to get it.
It just prints "**$1**" literal instead of value.

But if I add $2$3 like this, it displays "**.75HP**":

```
ActiveSheet.Range("H" & c.Row).value = regEx.Replace(strInput, "$2 $3")
```

Comment: Are your cells in column H formatted as currency or something?

Comment: Your code worked just fine for me.

Comment: @A.S.H Thank you, I changed it to General, and it is working.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by @A.S.H, My destination cell had formatting as 'Currency';
It worked after changing